# Angular-CLI: Specific Typings-Folder

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add some specific d.ts-Files from an ambient folder. Normally, they're added to the @types folder, but I can't do that in this case.
From my understanding, the CLI doesn't interact directly with the Typescript-Compiler, so my bet would be to enhance the tsconfig.json, for example like this:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types",
  "node_modules/@types2",
  "typings/tsd.d.ts"
],
```

@types2 is a test-folder of mine to test the behavior. I added for example the jQuery-Typings in the types2-folder. 
Then I import the jquery, for example:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Injectable()
export class VssUserService {

  public testJquery(): void {
    const emptyObj = {};
    const test = $.isEmptyObject(emptyObj);
  }
```

Interesting enought, just using the typescript compiler seems to work, but using the ng build command, I get:

> ERROR in
>   C:/MyGit/Personal/VSTS/BuildBuddy/src/app/common/core-services/vss/services/vss-user.service.ts
>   (9,20): Cannot find module 'jquery'.
>
> ERROR in
>   ./src/app/common/core-services/vss/services/vss-user.service.ts Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in
>   'C:\MyGit\Personal\VSTS\BuildBuddy\src\app\common\core-services\vss\services'

I feel like missing one puzzle piece, how the CLI and/or TypeScript are collecting the d.ts-files?